# Reverify phone number everytime i login like whats app using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

i want to Re verify phone number every time i login to firebase

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                   phone,        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    Main2Activity.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                            mVerificationId = verificationId;
                            mResendToken = token;
                        }
                   }
                    );
```

this code only dose it onetime after that it login without verification

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to verify phone number using firebase otp but it only verify the phone number using sms code only one i want to verify phone number every time i login

Comment: You can SignOut user every time. And then check if user is logged in or not is that simple.

Comment: it doesn't sent me the code again after the user is created it automatically sign in